# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Operations Research's [first moderator election](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: EhsanK] [image: LarrySnyder610] [image: TheSimpliFire]

They'll be [appointed as moderators](https://or.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5699417279561728/0).

Comment: Congrats, y’all! Thank you for serving, and thanks to Rob for your willingness.

Answer (score 11):

Good work guys, congratulations.

Comment: And thanks Rob for being such a great active user on the site!

Comment: @EhsanK you are all most welcome, the other Robert will stick around for a while to help you get settled in. There's a moderator chat room where you can visit to discuss site operation or obtain advice in private.

Comment: Adding my thanks too for your helpful contributions to both the site and the chatroom!

Answer (score 10):

Thanks, everyone! Looking forward to serving as a moderatOR!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, all. I’m looking forward to serving as a mod.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to all of the winning users and thank you to all the others that took part in the election!

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to all elected moderators. Thank you all for your voluntary service.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to everyone for your support by voting! Very looking forward to help monitor the site a lot more as a mod.